# An Inline element has more than 2 lines (one within the other)

Tags: css

I couldn't set inline elements background like this:

[image]

My code is this:

```
#divMansetKategoriHaberleriContainer
{
    background-color: Transparent;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.divKategoriHaberItem
{
    float: left;
    background-color: White;
    width: 324px;
    height: 126px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.divKategoriHaberItemImage
{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2px;
}
.imgKategoriHaberResim_Cevre
{
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
}
.divKategoriHaberItemBaslikIcerik
{
}
.spHaberBaslik_Cevre
{
    background-color: Green;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}

.spHaberIcerik_Cevre
{
    display: block;
}
.divKategoriHaberDevami_Cevre
{
    background-image: url('../images/HaberinDevami_Cevre.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 13px;
}




<div class="divKategoriHaberItem">
    <div class="divKategoriHaberItemImage">
        <img src='' alt='DÜNYANIN MEKANİK Dengesi Bozuldu' class="imgKategoriHaberResim_Cevre" />
    </div>
    <div class="divKategoriHaberItemBaslikIcerik">
        <span class="spHaberBaslik_Cevre">
           <a href='CevreHaber.aspx?id=2128'>DÜNYANIN MEKANİK Dengesi Bozul</a>
        </span>
        <span class="spHaberIcerik_Cevre">Demokratik Kongo Cumhuriyeti'n</span>
    </div>
    <div class="divKategoriHaberDevami_Cevre"></div>
</div>
```

PS: Sorry for i couldn't write with sentences :(

Comment: I don't see a problem in the CSS. So the problem is probably in the HTML or in another CSS rule. Please show the relevant snippets, preferably in flavor of an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) from `<!doctype html><html>` until with `</html>`

Comment: First line has a text. But it is one line. I just wanted to make its background color green. And i set its "padding:5px;" Because i wanted to make its starting and ending spaces longer (left, right, top and bottom spaces). But as you see, wrapped line looks like one within the other.

Comment: I now see (after I took my glasses off and studied the hugely constracted piece of flashblue+darkgreen in the screenshot at about 10cm from the screen). Well, the answer of Gaby has it right. You need to set `line-height`.

Comment: :) It was funny. So 10 cm ha!... :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you will need to add a line-height that equals the total height of your inline element ...

in your case that would be 30px (20px for the height + 10px for the padding 5px top and 5px bottom..)

```
.spHaberBaslik_Cevre
{
    background-color: Green;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:30px; /*height + padding-top +padding-bottom*/
}
```